# Trying to join two tables with multiple where condition on both table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote following sql query

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id, clicks.offer_name, clicks.country, clicks.device_type, clicks.os_name, conversions.name , clicks.ip_address as Session, conversions.conversion_ip as Conversion, conversions.currency as Currency , conversions.payout as Payout 
FROM clicks 
JOIN users ON clicks.affiliate_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN conversions ON clicks.transaction_id = conversions.click_transaction_id 
WHERE clicks.affiliate_id = '2' 
  AND conversions.status = ('approved' or 'pending') 
  AND date(clicks.created_at) BETWEEN '2021-11-08' AND '2021-12-07'
```

in where condition doesn't affect the following condition

```
AND conversions.status = ('approved' or 'pending')
```

What I did mistake here?

Comment: The condition by right table in LEFT JOIN must be placed into ON clause, not into WHERE. And this condition is not correct - you must use `AND conversions.status IN ('approved', 'pending')`.

Comment: `AND conversions.status IN('approved', 'pending') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IN operator in the WHERE clause like below;

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id, clicks.offer_name, 
clicks.country, clicks.device_type, clicks.os_name, 
conversions.name , clicks.ip_address as Session, 
conversions.conversion_ip as Conversion, 
conversions.currency as Currency , 
conversions.payout as Payout 
FROM clicks 
JOIN users ON clicks.affiliate_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN conversions ON clicks.transaction_id = conversions.click_transaction_id 
WHERE clicks.affiliate_id = '2' AND conversions.status IN ('approved', 'pending') 
AND date(clicks.created_at) BETWEEN '2021-11-08' AND '2021-12-07';
```